# Asus laptop wifi led not lighting

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

Last week i bought asus x555lb laptop and installed windows 10. And saw,
that wifi led is off, it light up only then I turn on air plane mode.

All drivers from asus web site are installed.

On my old laptop wifi led light was blinking, I dont know if it suppose on new asus. How to know this?

**Wifi connection is perfect.**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this model, there is no WiFi light (A WiFi LED indicator isn't very common on laptops now, it featured before WiFi was a near certainty to appear on a laptop).

The light you're referring to indicates that you are in airplane mode. As such, it is function exactly as intended.

[image]

Comment: User manual says:
Bluetooth / Wireless indicator
This indicator lights up when your Notebook PC’s
wireless function (Bluetooth or Wi-Fi) is enabled.

Comment: But mine is off.

Comment: You're right, the [manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X555LB/0409_E9105_B.pdf) does say this, however if it DID behave like that, the picture of an airplane would be very misleading as that would indicate to me it's in airplane mode. Honestly, if everything is working, I really wouldn't worry about it, I believe they've made a mistake in the manual rather than with the indicator.